# GPU's performance mainly depends on which factor

Tags: gpu, gpgpu

There are many specs given about a GPU. I want to know by which single factor its performance can be measured; would it be based on pixels/sec, clock speed, number of cores, amount of memory, memory speed, flops/sec or any other thing. I want to know the answer both for graphic processing and mathematical computations.

Comment: Overall performance is measured by all of them.  For a given task...well, it depends on the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cores and memory type/speed is two factors that count alot '
and it also depends on the manufacturer , nvidia has less cores but they are faster compared to the high number of amd ones use in theirs gpus, but they are around same performance level

a 1600 cores (stream units) gpu with GDDR5 5000mhz is faster than a 1600 cores (stream units) gpu with DDR3 1600mhz

another example is
a 1400 cores (stream units) gpu with GDDR5 6000mhz can be close to a 1600 core (stream units) gpu with DDR3 1600mhz

there is no single factor, unless you count benchmarks